# How to CPU-efficiently add a trillion numbers?

Tags: algorithm, performance, optimization, data-structures

Assume each number is of size close to max int, but is slightly different (identical numbers are allowed)

- eg. 2,147,483,646
- eg. 2,945,283,647
- eg. 2,643,483,500
- etc...

I am sure using a loop would fail in this case, simply because the program would abort with time-out error.

Comment: Well summing up *n* numbers takes (with fixed word size), at least *O(n)*, since every number matters here. The only thing you can do is *parallelize* the thing. If however the data is not that random, but has a certain structure, we sometimes can exploit this.

Comment: Is this a practical need or are you just curious? A trillion numbers is about 4 terabytes of binary data. You need to ask yourself how to *read* four terabytes first. In addition, if each number is close to 2^32, their sum will overflow the 64-bit data type.

Comment: Also, loops don't "time out." A timeout is something added by programmers.

Comment: Telling us the motivation for asking this might help get the type of answer you're looking for.

Comment: pick 1 million at random, add them up, multiply by 1000000, and randomize the last 6 digits. Noone will know :) .

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy A trillion is about 2^40, so if the trillion values are on the average 2^30, the sum will be approximately 2^70, which will not fit in a 64-bit type.  For a 64-bit unsigned integral type, the average value would have to be something lower than 2^24.

Comment: @DavidThornley `A trillion is about 2^40` That would be a USofA trillion. A British  trillion is (used to be?) 10^18 or close to 2^60. At a rate of, say, 2^33 additions/second, that takes about the lifetime of a single electronic adder/accumulator even in redundant representation → see [Willem Van Onsem's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54658627/how-to-cpu-efficiently-add-a-trillion-numbers/54659524#comment96108744_54658627).

Comment: @David Thornley:  You're right, of course.  I miscounted the nybbles in my programmer's calculator when I tried to check my work.  I'll delete my comment.

Answer (score 0):

There's no getting around a trillion operations for the addition of a trillion numbers, which will take a while.  Since we're talking about four terabytes, we're probably talking about numbers loaded into SSDs at best, and the CPU time will be much smaller than the time needed to read a trillion numbers from SSDs.

It's easy to do this in parallel, as long as we make sure the data access is parallel.  Having a large number of CPUs reading a trillion numbers from one SSD isn't going to speed things up.

The sum isn't going to fit into a 64-bit number, but if each number is within about 2^24 of maxint, it would be possible to add the differences between maxint and each individual number, and that will fit in a 64-bit unsigned integer.